# Using SAM deploy without preceding build

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

I'm currently developing a SAM application and when I compare running `sam deploy` with vs. without invoking `sam build` beforehand, both seem to work. What's the difference? Can I skip `sam build`?